# Select childs of a class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a code in html similar of

```
<div class="form">
<form>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

and I would like to select all inputs of the div which have a attribute class=form

I tried this in CSS but without success:

```
.form > input {}
div[class="form"] > input {}
div[class=form] > input {}
```

So please how to select childs elements of a class in CSS ?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Classes do not have children. The sample code posted has no “inputs of the div which have a attribute class=form”. Although it might be possible to guess what you actually mean, a question should be understandable without guesswork, to help future visitors.

Comment: Do you actually mean how to select all `input` descendants of the `div` that *has* (i.e. the `div` has) the attribute `class=form`? If so, please edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

`>` means child, while in your code `input` is not a **child** (or a direct descendant) of `div`.

you should use descendant selector:

```css
.form input {}
div input {}
```

if you want a child selector, these are correct:

```css
.form > form > input {}
div > form > input {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div.form form input { ... }
```

you can target a div which have a class like this `div.classname`

Answer (score 1):

It should work with

```
.form input {
    /*your css code*/
}
```

Do not use the `>` in this case, it only selects the direct children

Answer (score 0):

If you want all inputs in your form class styled:

```
.form input {}
```

what you used

```
>
```

is a selector. For more information on selectors look at this link [Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are basically need all the inputs inside div with class="form". Below is the CSS for it.

```
.form input
{
  /*Your css for the inputs*/   
}
```

Your could also write it as-

```
div.form input
{
  /*Your css for the inputs*/   
}
```